# What are the racial skill modifiers for Dragons?

Tags: pathfinder-1e

I'm interested in determining the skill modifiers for a [Gold Dragon](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/monsters/dragon.html#_metallic-dragon-gold) for Pathfinder, for a one-shot game for a friend where they play a dragon. Dragons have massive perception modifiers  which can probably be deduced from their stats (wis, one rank per skill, etc) but is there any information anywhere else about any other skill modifiers for dragons (such as fly!)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Gold dragons have no racial ability modifiers.**
In fact, you could reverse engineer them.

[Dragons](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/monsters/creatureTypes.html#_dragon) have these class skills: Appraise, Bluff, Climb, Craft, Diplomacy, Fly, Heal, Intimidate, Knowledge (all), Linguistics, Perception, Sense Motive, Spellcraft, Stealth, Survival, Swim, and Use Magic Device.

For example, a [Young Gold Dragon](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/monsters/dragon.html#_metallic-dragon-gold) has 9 skill points per HD (6 for being a dragon, +3 for Int modifier). His stat block enumerates 9 skills, so I think designers put max ranks (12) in each of them.

The dragon's Perception modifier is +22 which coincides with: 12 from ranks, +3 from being class skill, +3 from Wisdom and +4 from the [Alertness](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/feats.html#_alertness) feat. Being so, it seems that Gold Dragons have no racial Perception bonus.

The same breakdown is valid for Sense Motive (Pathfinder's [Alertness](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/feats.html#_alertness) applies to that skill too).

A quick scan through the other skills reveals that no racial modifiers are applied. The oddball here is the [Fly](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/skills/fly.html#_fly) skill, which includes Size and maneuverability modifiers. Its breakdown is: +10 = 12 ranks, +3 class skill, +1 Dex, -2 Large size, -4 poor maneuverability.

Comment: Fantastic! Thanks very much, excellent answer. I'm impressed with Pazio too it must be said; with all the skills and whatnot matching up to the game mechanics for each monster, a lot of thought and care there.
The game has now expanded somewhat due to enthusiasm from other players, looks like I'm giving them each 10 CR to play with and any good aligned monster to play.